# converting .jar to .dll using ikvm.net warning?

Tags: dll, jar, android-activity, ikvm

I have made an android project library, In this project there is only one class. This class is used to get the path of the selected image from the gallery or saved image from camera.

Here is the class.

```
public class ImageBrowse extends Activity  {
private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private Uri selectedImageUri;
private static String imageRealPath = null;
private String imageName = null;
public String BrowseImageFromGallery(){
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
    if(imageRealPath != null)
    {
        return imageRealPath;
    }
    return null;
}

public String TakeImageFromCamera(){

    TakeImage();
    return imageRealPath;
}

@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent ){

    switch (resultCode){

    case GALLERY_REQUEST : {
        selectedImageUri = intent.getData();
        imageRealPath = GetRealPathFromUri(selectedImageUri);
    }
    break;

    case CAMERA_REQUEST : {
        imageRealPath = GetRealPathFromUri(selectedImageUri);
    }
    break;
    }

}

private String GetRealPathFromUri(Uri imageUri) {

    try
    {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(imageUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_Index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_Index);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return imageUri.getPath();
    }
}

private void TakeImage() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     imageName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, imageName);
    selectedImageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            values);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, selectedImageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

}
```

}

> I want to use this class from .net, therefore i used IKVM.NET. But i got the warning unable to compile the class ImageBrowse.
>   below is the image for the warning.

[image: Warning]

> How to remove this warning??

Answer (score 0):

You can not use IKVM to convert an Android project. IKVM work only with Java SE and Java EE files. IKVM does not contains the Android runtime.

Also you need to add the IKVM runtime to your project. This are 40 MB. This is a large overhead for only one class. It is simpler to convert the source code of this class to C#.